# How to add custom pre-saved command line (via CMD) on the Windows context menu?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, context-menu, desktop-customization

I'm calling for you because I'm a big fan of Windows tweaks, customization and tricks. Often have some ideas to customize my Windows and save time with a new workflow, BUT I'm not very good in coding, software etc. I'm good at following instructions, tutorial etc. Most of the time I find all I want and need on Google because I know how and where to search. And sometimes (like now) I don't really find any accurate solutions. Let me explain quickly:

(Windows 10 PC)

Let's say I want to add a custom context-menu option which will allow me to copy a folder structure without copying the content of each folders (precise example, I don't know why... that's just for a friend lol)

I know that I can "simply" put it together thanks to CMD, with the following command line:

```
xcopy, "source", "destination" /t /e
```

Or the following Rebocopy command line:

```
robocopy, "source", "destination" /e /xf *
```

(Thanks to Google search, obviously)

Is there a way to add this to a quick access context menu option ?
I guess it might be tricky because the command line asks for a source folder and a destination folder, and the quick access context menu option should then be divided in 2; Copy source structure (by clicking on the source folder) | Paste to destination (by clicking on the destination folder)

Is it even possible ?

Good to mention that I already have some tools to customize my context menu (FileMenu Tools and Easy Context Menu) but none of them allow me to add such a precise shortcut.

To ask it in a wider range, is there a way to add a pre-saved CMD command in Context-menu shortcut ?

Thanks a lot, like, endlessly, it would open a whole new world of possibilities to my Windows custom tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but I just figured this out for myself.

You need to open the Windows registry (`regedit.exe`) and navigate to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell

There you can create a new key (folder) that you can name whatever you want. That key must contain another key named `command` and in the "Default" keyset you add your command. I've created a helper for the most often used maven commands. In my example that executes

```
cmd.exe /k mvn clean install -DskipTests
```